# jQuery post data to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, servlets

I'm having some problems posting data from a web page, using jQuery, to a servlet.  While I'm an experienced Java developer, I'm very new to javascript/jQuery/servlets.  I'm using Eclipse, Apache Tomcat, and Chrome.

I have an XML file (from 6KB to 30MB in size) that I wish to load into the browser, modify, then post to the servlet.

My HTML has:

```
<input id="filechooser" type="file" onchange="readFile()">
```

My JS has:

```
var file = document.getElementById('filechooser').files[0];
var reader;
reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
reader.onload = loaded;
function loaded(evt){
   var result = evt.target.result;
   var xml = $(result);
   ...
   [make modifications to xml]
}
```

Some jQuery code that I use in modifying the xml are `$(xml).find("NODE").val()` and `$(xml).find("OTHER_NODE").attr("attribute-name","newValue")`

I now need to post that xml to a URL, where it will be used to process some information.  In the Chrome console, I can view the content of the xml object:

```
> xml
  [<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->,#text,
   <root_element>...</root_element>]

> $(xml)
  [<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?-->,#text,
   <root_element>...</root_element>]

> console.dir(xml)
  jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[3]
     0: #comment
     1: #text
     2: root_element
     length: 3
     __proto__: Object[0]
```

My servlet is empty so far:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   System.out.println("Post");
}
```

I created a button that executes some javascript.  The following two code snippets both post to the server:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/MyWebAppUrl", xml);
```

and:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/MyWebAppUrl",
   data: xml
});
```

My problem is, I don't know if I'm sending my XML correctly, or how to properly consume it.  What do I need to do to my jQuery code to post it correctly?  How do I get it out of my HttpServletRequest?  If I can get the xml text as a String, I know exactly how to manipulate it in Java, and get it to do whatever I want.

After 10+ hours searching the web, I still can't find the answer.  I'm sure it's out there, but I can't seem to connect the dots.

UPDATE:

epascarello was spot on for posting an XML document.  However, I was parsing the document incorrectly.

Notice that I read the file, then stored the result `var xml = $(result)`.  The file was read as a text string, and I was converting it to an HTML document.

What I needed to do was `var xml = jQuery.parseXML(result)`.  That way, I didn't have to convert it back to a text string, and tag capitalizing is maintained.

Note that maintaining capitalization is of critical important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the content type

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/xml",  //or text/xml?
   url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/MyWebAppUrl",
   data: xml
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried setting the content type to "application/xml" and "text/xml", but neither worked.  I ran wireshark to take a look at the actual post data, and it looks like the XML content is:

`undefined=&undefined=&undefined=`

When I read the buffer from the request, it also contained `"undefined=&undefined=&undefined="`

Comment: I figured out what my problem was.  I was trying to submit an object.  I needed to convert it to a string like so:  
  
   `jQuery("div").append(xml.clone()).remove().html();`  
  
That creates a <div></div> object, appends a clone of my xml object, then converts it to a string.  I pass that string to my servlet, and let JDOM do the rest.

Comment: Correction:  `jQuery("<div>").append(xml.clone()).remove().html();`  
  
I forgot the `<>` around the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `processData: false` to your call and it should leave the string alone...

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/xml",  //or text/xml?
   url: "http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/MyWebAppUrl",
   data: xml,
   processData: false
});
```